# SQL Server database design with foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys

I have the following partial database design:

[image: Partial database design]

All the tables are dependent on each other so the table `bvd_docflow_subdocuments` is dependent on the table `bdd_docflow_subsets`

and the table `bvd_docflow_subdocuments` is dependent on `bvd_docflow_subsets`. So I thought I could me smart and use foreign keys on every table (and `ON DELETE CASCADE`). However the FK are being drilldown how further I go in to the tables.

The problem is the table `bvd_docflow_documents` has no point having a reference to the 1docflow_documentset_id` PK / FK. Is there a way (and maybe my design is crappy) that only the table standing above it has an FK relationship between the tables and not all the tables above it.

**Edit:**

More explanation:

In the `bvd_docflow_subsets` table information is stored about objects to create documents. There is an relation between that table and `bvd_docflow_subdocuments` table (This table stores master data about all the documents for an subset. (`docflow_subset_id` is in both tables). This is the link between those to tables.

Going further down we also got the table `bvd_docflow_documents` this table contains the actual document data. The link between `bvd_docflow_documents` and `bvd_docflow_subdocuments` is `bvd_docflow_subdocument_id`.

On every table I got an foreign key defined so when data is removed on a table all the data linked to that data is also removed.

However when we look to the `bvd_docflow_documents` table it has all the foreign keys from the other tables (docflow_subset_id and docflow_documentset_id) and there is the problem. The only foreign key needed for that `bvd_docflow_documents` table is `docflow_subdocument_id` and no other.

**Edit 2**

I have changed my design further and removed information that I don't need after initial import of the data.

See the following link for the (total) databse design:
https://sqldbm.com/Project/SQLServer/Share/_AUedvNutCEV2DGLJleUWA

The tables `subsets`, `subdocuments` and `documents` have a many to many relationship so I thought a table in between those 3 `documents_subdocuments` is the way to go were I define all the different keys for those tables.

I am not used to the database design first and then build it. But, for everything there is a first time, and I try to do make a database that is using standards and is using the power of SQL Server the correct way.

Comment: Might want to ask that here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here. Can you try to explain the issue more clearly?

Comment: Added some extra explantion, hope is more clear now

Comment: They don't depend on each other. There is one-way dependency, a hierarchy. PK design lacks sense. With different IDENTITY value you may have same values for all other columns. Once you make your PKs to consist of a single IDENTITY column you will not have to "drill down" all the accumulated IDs from the hierarchy upper levels.

Comment: So PK is really useless within this design? Or I need to change the design that the IDENTITY column on all tables are the same?

Comment: Your PK design seems to be very wrong. This does not mean that "PKs are useless".

Comment: No just within this design :-). Can you point me in the right direction? Or is that to much to ask?

Comment: Already did in my first reply @PatrickRennings

Comment: Just wondering, what did you use to design the database?

Comment: sqldbm.com, great online tool

Answer (score 2):

I'll address the bottom-most table and ignore the rest for the most part.

But first some comments. Your schema is simply a model of a system. To provide feedback, one must understand this "system" and how it actually works to evaluate your model. In addition, it is important to understand your entities and your reasons for choosing them and modelling them in the specified manner. Without that understanding all of this guessing based on experience.

And another comment. Slapping an identity column into every table is just lazy modelling IMO. Others will disagree, but you need to also enforce all natural keys. Do you have natural keys? It is rare not to have **any**. Enforce those that do exist.

And one last comment. Stop the ridiculous pattern of prepending the column names with the table names. And you should really think long and hard about using very long table names. Given what you have, I sense you need a schema for your docflow stuff.

For the documents table, your current PK makes no sense. Again, you've slapped an identity column into the table. By itself, this column is a key for the table. The inclusion of any other columns does not make the key any more "unique" - that inclusion is logical nonsense. Following your pattern, you would designate the identity column as the primary key. But ...

According to your image, the documents table is related to one and only one subdocument. You added a foreign key to that table - which matches the image. You also added additional columns and foreign keys to the "higher" tables. So now a document "points" to a specific subdocument. It also points to a specific subset - which may have no relationship to the subdocument. The same thought applies to the other FK. I have a doubt that this is logically correct. So why do these columns (and related FKs) exist? Perhaps this is the result of premature optimization - which everyone knows is the root of all evil coding. Again, it is impossible to know if this is "right" or even "useful" for your model.

To answer your question "... is there a way", the answer is obviously yes. You remove the columns of which you complain. You added them - Why? Is this perhaps a problem with the tool you are using?

And some last comments. There is nothing special about "varchar(50)". Perhaps this is a place holder that will be updated later. It may also be another sign of laziness. And generally speaking, columns with names like "type" and "code" tend to be foreign keys to "lookup" tables - because people like to add, modify, or remove these sorts categorization values over time. I'm also concerned about the column name overlap among the tables. "Location" exists in multiple tables, as do action_code and action_id. And a column named "id" (action_id) suggests a lookup to another table - is it? Should it be? Is there a relationship between action_id and action_code? From a distance it is impossible to answer any of these questions.

But designing a database is more art than science. Sometimes you just need to create something, populate it with some sample data, and then determine if it works for your needs. Everyone will get something wrong in the first try. That is expected; that is how you learn. The most difficult part is actually completing your first attempt.

Comment: I edited my first post with a changed design could you take a look? I do not have any natural keys because the input for these documents is a generated XML document with no unique id's and there isnt a reall unique identifier. My thoughts where to make the `documentset_id` the "head key" to control the rest of the set.